# Spring MVCのプロジェクトを作成後、「Maven Install」時のエラー

Tags: java, spring

OSはWindows10でJAVAのverは1.8を使用しています。
Spring MVCのプロジェクトを作成後、プロジェクトに対して、右クリック、「Maven Install」を行うと下記のようなエラーがでます。
「Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0」
どう修正すればエラーは改善できますでしょうか。
あとプロジェクトの中のJREシステムライブラリが「JAVASE-1.6」と表記されていることや
コンソールに「(省略)\pleiades\java\6\bin」と表記されているところも気になります。
●pom.xmlの中身(一部)

```
    <name>Sample_MVC</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下にあるように, Java7以上を使う必要があるようです。
そのため、プロジェクトで仕様しているJREシステムライブラリを1.7以上に変更すると良いと思います。

[Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 = Java7 以上使え](https://qiita.com/seratch@github/items/731b69d3edabe9c8bc0d)